# How to manually download extensions from Magento installation and install in another

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I'm trying to move all the extensions from our main site to our development site. I found the extensions in app/code/community.. can I just copy and paste them in the same file path on the development site and they be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't be enough and I don't recommend to do that as it is error-prone (and lots of work to copy all the files/folders seperate).

A magento extension consists at least of:

- Source code in `app/code/community` or `app/code/local`
- Module XML in `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml`

There might also be additional files such as translation files in `app/locale/xx_XX/Namespace_Module.csv`, layout xml-files and templates,...

I recommend you create a list of the needed extensions and install them in your new shop via [modman](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman) or [composer](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer).